# Erro com o Apache no Windows 10

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Bom... antes de atualizar para o win 10 , o apache funcionava certinho, tanto com o WAMP, XAMMP, EasyPHP, etc.. depois que atualizei para o win 10 abro o xammp , e quando vou startar o Apache, recebo esse seguinte erro:

> 20:34:36  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>   20:34:36  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>   20:34:36  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>   20:34:36  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>   20:34:36  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>   20:34:36  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
>   20:34:36  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums

Pelo que percebi, executando o EasyPHP, ele diz que a porta 80 já está sendo usada por outro aplicativo, porém esse é um aplicativo do sistema, e não tem como finalizar,

tem como eu mudar essa porta 80, para que funcione ? ou o que tenho que fazer?

Comment: [localhost não funciona win10](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80485/91)

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma resposta no [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29602112/929324) (inglês).

Uma possível solução é que o Windows 10 vem com um serviço chamado Word Wide Web Publishing Service (não sei o nome em português) e ele acaba bloqueando a porta 80.
Se for este o seu caso você deve acessar o gerenciador de serviços do windows e pará-lo.

Este problema também pode acontecer com outros programas como Skype, Teamviewer e outros bloqueando a porta. A ideia é tentar descobrir qual aplicativo está causando o problema e pará-lo.

Outra provável solução mostrada foi re-instar o [Visual C++ Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) e depois re-instalar o WAMP/XAMPP.

Comment: Utilizo apache no windows 10, nunca tive problemas com a porta 80 que não fosse o Skype, acredito que seja 98% dos casos, ele inclusive já oferece opção de não utilizar nas suas configurações, por isso daria essa checada primeiro, e por isso meu upvote pra esse cara!

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma pergunta parecia com a sua e tive uma reposta que resolve este problema:

O que acontece é que existe um serviço provavelmente ligado ao IIS(express acredito) que também é um servidor web, ele vem por padrão ativado, para resolver isso sem trocar a porta padrão do apache, aperte winkey + R e digite services.msc procure por: Serviço de Publicação da World Wide Web e deixe esse serviço para ser iniciado manualmente.